# Why are some links not returning a referer from the request header?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have almost finished building a web crawler based off of Scrapy's CrawlSpider, whose purpose is to crawl through a site checking for broken external links. The crawler tests external links and reports the HTTP status code, the link text, and the page the link was found on.

```
def external_url(self, response):
        item = linkList()
        item['link_text'] = response.meta['link_text']
        item['link_url'] = response.url
        item['link_status'] = response.status
        item['link_location'] = response.request.headers.get('Referer', None)
```

I've noticed, however, that about 1/3 of the external links checked do not return a referer url. I've sorted my results via url, and it seems that certain domains just don't return referers. I checked the HTTP status codes, and almost all of the URLs returned `200`. I've tried changing the `REFERER_POLICY` from default to `unsafe_url`, as that seemed like the only option that guaranteed sending a referer link in the header, but that didn't change the results. Is there anything that I can do about this, or could this be a problem with the external domains?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the `REFERER_POLICY` on the website was preventing the request from containing the referrer information. I spoke with the webmaster, and had the setting on the subdomain changed to `unsafe_url`, and I no longer get empty `link_location` fields.